# TFS Code Review an error occurred while updating the code review's state

Tags: tfs

I'm getting the error below while trying to send code review.

> An error occurred while submitting the code review request and attempt to rollback also failed. the page will be closed. Details: an error occurred while updating the code review's state

I'm using VS 2015 and TFS 2018

Comment: Are you able to submit code review before?

Answer (score 0):

To narrow down the issue, please try the following items:

1. Close all VS instances, and clean the cache folder: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache.`
2. Test on another machine to see whether you can reproduce this issue.
3. Ask other team members to submit a code review to see whether they have any issue.